# GSAP ScrollTrigger - как сделать плавную анимацию clip-path?

Tags: javascript, анимация, path, gsap

[Реализация в CodePen](https://codepen.io/Coder10000000000/pen/BaJmoaG)

В данном примере реализована анимация через последовательное изменения свойства "clip-path"

Но почему-то между состояниями нет плавного перехода. Как сделать анимацию плавной?

HTML

```
<section class="rotate">
    <div class="rotate-polygon"></div>
</section>
```

CSS

```
.rotate{
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: black;

  &-polygon {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: red;
    clip-path: polygon(0 25%, 100% 25%, 100% 75%, 0 75%);
  }
}
```

JS

```
gsap.timeline({repeat: -1, repeatDelay: 1},{
    scrollTrigger: {
        trigger: ".rotate",
        duration: 2,
    }
})
    .to(".rotate-polygon", {
    "clip-path": "polygon(0 50%, 50% 0, 100% 50%, 50% 100%)",
    ease: Power3.easeOut,
    duration: 1,
}, )
    .to(".rotate-polygon", {
    "clip-path": "polygon(0 75%, 0 25%, 100% 25%, 100% 75%)",
    ease: Power3.easeOut,
    duration: 1,
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно значения в polygon указывать в %, даже 0

```js
gsap.timeline({repeat: -1, repeatDelay: 1},{
    scrollTrigger: {
        trigger: ".rotate",
        duration: 2,
    }
})
    .to(".rotate-polygon", {
    "clip-path": "polygon(0% 50%, 50% 0%, 100% 50%, 50% 100%)",
    ease: Power3.easeOut,
    duration: 1,
}, )
    .to(".rotate-polygon", {
    "clip-path": "polygon(0% 75%, 0% 25%, 100% 25%, 100% 75%)",
    ease: Power3.easeOut,
    duration: 1,
});
```

Comment: Спасибо, сработало!